# Cannot access foreign key elements in html templates DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-templates, foreign-keys

Views:

```
def search_devis(request):
devis = Devis.objects.all()
commercial = User.objects.all()
client = Client.objects.all()

context={
    'devis': devis,
    'commercial': commercial,
    'client_': client,

}
return render(request, "manage_devis/search_devis.html",context )
```

Models:

```
class Devis(models.Model):
titre = models.CharField(max_length=30, )
date_ecriture = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
date_expiration = models.DateField()
client = models.ForeignKey(Client, name="CLIENT_FK", default=1 ,on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
commercial = models.ForeignKey(User, name="COMMERCIALFK", default=1 ,on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
def __str__(self):
    return "DV"+str(self.pk)
```

Templates:

```
{% for devis_ in devis %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><a href="{% url 'view_devis' devis_.pk %}">DV{{devis_.id }}</a></th>
    <td>{{ devis_.date_ecriture }}</td>
    <td>{{ devis_.date_expiration }}</td>
    <td>{{devis_.client.nom}}</td>
    <td>{{ devis_.total}} DH</td>
    <td>{{ devis_.commercial.last_name}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I can't display the attributes of the foreign key object, no value in it.
nothing appear in the column.
I'm using postgresql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try removing the `name="CLIENT_FK"` in the model and then make the migration (`python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`).
Your model now should look something like:

```
class Devis(models.Model):
titre = models.CharField(max_length=30, )
date_ecriture = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
date_expiration = models.DateField()
client = models.ForeignKey(Client, default=1 ,on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
commercial = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1 ,on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
def __str__(self):
    return "DV"+str(self.pk)
```

After that, you can iterate in your forloop, please, avoid using something like devis_. I suggest you to use a forloop like this:

```
{% for dev in devis %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><a href="{% url 'view_devis' dev.pk %}">DV{{dev.id }}</a></th>
    <td>{{ dev.date_ecriture }}</td>
    <td>{{ dev.date_expiration }}</td>
    <td>{{dev.client.nom}}</td>
    <td>{{ dev.total}} DH</td>
    <td>{{ dev.commercial.last_name}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.I've been struggling with it for so long.

Comment: If it worked, you may accept the answer if it was useful. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Try `{% for devis in object.devis_set.all %}`
And don’t use _ at the end of the devis

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

it's not working, it says No data available in table.